# OnTrigger2D doesn't seem to be called

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am facing a problem with unity on a 2D project. OnTriggerEnter2D doesn't seem to be called as I have no prints on console.

Here is the script that calls the OnTriggerEnter2D

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AbilityUnlock : MonoBehaviour
{
    

    
     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Test");
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Player tag ");

            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }


}
```

gameObject Collider

[image: The Collider of the object Is trigger is on]!

Project Collisions

[image: The Project Collisions]

RigidBody2D of the Player

[image: The rigidbody 2D of the player]

Tag of the Player

[image: The Tag of the Player and the Layer]

The Script is attached to the gameObject.

Probably I am missing something that I can't see.Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does your player have a collider on it?

Answer (score 0):

There are five things I always check when having trigger enter issues.

1. Both objects are on physics layers that can interact with each other
2. Both objects to have `collider2d` components
3. The *entered* object has a `rigidbody2d` component
4. The *entered* object's `collider2d` is set to `trigger`
5. The *entering* object's `collider2d` is not set to `trigger`

From your question it look like you've already got steps **1)** and **4)** looking good.

As other answers point out the most likely candidate is **3)** - `rigidbody2d` not being on your *entered* object.

If none of that works, then you can try some more extreme measures such as setting the rigidbodys to never sleep or playing with the interpolation mode, but give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out the gameObject that has the collider2D didn't have the Player tag even though it is a child of the player gameObject.Appling The Player Tag to the gameObject that has the collider2D and not to his parent fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need Rigidbody2d Component on gameObject. Not only on player.